# Is necessary to install exchange server for sending emails in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, incoming-email, exchange-server, smtp

Need little clarification about email configuration. I'm using sharepoint 2013 and I have configured SMTP server, incoming mail config, outgoing mail config but I couldn't success to send emails.

I have done all configurations well . I have read some articles about exchange server for emails.
So,Is necessary to install exchange server for sending/receiving emails?
Can you please anyone give little suggestions for email configurations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use Exchange server to send e-mails. An advantage of SharePoint is in that You can use any smtp server You want. By example You can configure to send [with gmail](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/10/26/configuring-outgoing-email-settings-in-sharepoint-with-gmail-smtp.aspx). You can use local smtp too, but imho You should be carefull with spam attacks in that case

Comment: thank you Gennady.. I have a user praveeng@sp.net. and now How do I open this user account for sending emails ?(UI like outlook)

Comment: One restriction is that SharePoint does not let you use an SMTP that requires authentication. To do that, you usually install a local SMTP server and configure it to relay the e-mails to another server, with authentication and make it so the local SMTP accepts mail requests only from itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly this idea is described when sending via gmail.